# cufft.lib for win32 is missing

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to use cuda for image processing.

I need fft for low-pass filter, so I've tried to use cufft, and now I found that there is no cufft.lib for win32 in "NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\win32".

It only exists in x64 folder.

Can I use cufft for x64 only? or am I missing something on installation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [CUDA 7 release notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#unsupported-features):

> **Certain CUDA Features on 32-bit and 32-on-64-bit Windows Systems**
>
> The
>   CUDA Toolkit no longer supports 32-bit Windows operating systems.
>   Furthermore, the Windows CUDA Driver no longer supports Tesla and
>   Quadro products on 32-bit Windows operating systems. Additionally, on
>   64-bit Windows operating systems, the following features are no longer
>   supported by the CUDA driver or CUDA toolkit:
>
> - Running 32-bit
>     applications on Tesla and Quadro products
> - Using the Thrust library
>     from 32-bit applications
> - 32-bit versions of the CUDA Toolkit
>     scientific libraries, including cuBLAS, cuSPARSE, cuFFT, cuRAND, and
>     NPP
> - 32-bit versions of the CUDA samples

So no, there is no longer a 32 bit version of CUFFT shipped on Windows platforms as of CUDA 7.